# Counting with Principle of inclusion-exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Find the number of permutations of $
(1, 2,...,n)$ such that no number remains in its original place.

Solution: To do this, first we are going to count the number of permutations where at
least one number remains in its place, according to the inclusion-exclusion principle, we must first add the permutations where a given number is
fixed, then subtract the permutations where 2 given numbers are fixed and so on.

To find a permutation that fixes $k$ given elements, we only have to arrange the rest,
which can be done in $(n − k)!$ ways. However, if we do this for every choice of
$k$ elements, we are counting ${n \choose
k}(n − k)! = \frac{n!}{k!} $ permutations. Since in total there are $n!$ permutations we get as our result:$$n!-\left(\frac{n!}{1!}+\frac{n!}{2!}-\frac{n!}{3!}+...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n!}{n!}\right)$$
I'm a bit confused about a point of the solution, when we fix $k$ elements and rearrange the other $n-k$, some of the remaining elements will stay fixed in their position right? so why does this work?

Comment: This works because you are counting the number of permutations with *at least* $k$ elements in there original position.

Comment: Yes, that is the point of the adding and subtracting (inclusion-exclusion): to fix the over-counting that results because "some of the remaining elements will stay fixed in their position," as you noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion seems to be with the inclusion-exclusion principle in itself: when we say that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ it is precisely because $A$ and $B$ have some elements in common, those of $A\cap B$, and we are counting them twice, once in $|A|$ and again in $|B|$. In your problem it is the same, you look first at those permutations which have *at least* one fixed element, so you continue with the inclusion-exclusion principle until you take into account all the ``common elements''.

Comment: Okay so, when I count the number of permutations that fix at least one element I have ${n \choose 1}(n-1)!$ , so what happens is we fix only the first element and permute the others, then we fix only the second and permute and so on... once I've done this, if I take $n! - {n \choose 1}(n-1)!$ I would remove all the permutations s.t. at least one element is fixed, but, when I do so, some of the cases that occured during that $n$ permutations will be overcounted because when we permute the $n-1$ remaining elements we'll end up with some cases that were previously counted, that's it right?

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic That's more or less it! I'll try to give a more precise explanation (since you are using "at least one element fixed" in the wrong place). When you remove from all permutations the first $n!/1!$ term, you are removing those which have one fixed element and $n-1$ *arbitrary*. But if they are arbitrary, some repetitions will occur, so you are not removing all permutations s.t. at least one element is fixed, but only a lower bound of that. Then you realize that you have overcounted permutations with at least $2$ fixed elements, and you bound that quantity by below by $n!/2!$...

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic ...but then you have overcounted permutations with at least 3 fixed elements when you tried to fix the problem with 2-fixed permutations from 1-fixed ones; so you approximate the error by $n!/3!$ and keep going.

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic In the same vein, when you have 3 sets, $|A\cup B\cup C|\leq|A|+|B|+|C|$ but we have counted $|A\cap B|,|A\cap C|,|B\cap C|$ twice each, so we remove them once, but then we have removed $|A\cap B\cap C|$ thrice and we included it thrice in our first approximation, so we have no $|A\cap B\cap C|$ contribution and we have to include it, to get $$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-(|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|)+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

Comment: Yeah! I explained it poorly but fortunately I understand the intuition behind it now, it's actually the first time I apply PIE so I apologize for the rather silly question, Thanks!

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic You are welcome, and no need to apologize, questions may be silly (I don't think this is one), but doubts and silliness are better out than in!